# Elasticsearch query cache not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch, query-cache

I have an index enabled with query cache and it utilizes 10% of the heap memory. To understand the working I have reinitiated the index and cleared all the stats.

This is the stats of cache before executing the query:

```
"query_cache": {
       "memory_size": "0b",
       "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
       "total_count": 0,
       "hit_count": 0,
       "miss_count": 0,
       "cache_size": 0,
       "cache_count": 0,
       "evictions": 0
     }
```

This is the filter context:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": 
      [{"term": {"id": "1666"}},
      {"terms": {"skip": [0]}}]
      } 
  }
}
```

This fetches around 4K documents and this is what is the stats after executing it 3 times.

```
        "query_cache": {
          "memory_size": "6.7kb",
          "memory_size_in_bytes": 6932,
          "total_count": 6,
          "hit_count": 1,
          "miss_count": 5,
          "cache_size": 1,
          "cache_count": 1,
          "evictions": 0
        }
```

I was expecting the miss_count to be 1 for first time of execution and rest of the times hit_count will be incremented. But it does not seem like it.

Here is the stats of segments

```
index - my_index 
shard - 0
prirep - p
segment - _jj
generation - 703 
docs.count - 28192
docs.deleted - 190
size - 163.4mb
size.memory - 0
committed - true
searchable - true 
version - 9.5.0
compound - true
```

Can anyone explain how it works please ?

Comment: From the [official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-cache.html): `Caching is done on a per segment basis if a segment contains at least 10000 documents and the segment has at least 3% of the total documents of a shard.` can you confirm it's the case for you?

Comment: Yes. My index has a total of 28k documents. So I use only one shard.

Comment: Can you share the result you get from `GET _cat/segments?v`?

Comment: This is specifically to my index ::
index  - my_index ,
shard  - 0 ,
prirep - p ,
segment - _jj ,
generation - 703 ,
docs.count  - 28192 ,
docs.deleted   - 190 ,
size - 163.4mb ,
size.memory - 0 ,
committed - true ,
searchable - true ,
version - 9.5.0 ,
compound - true

Comment: Please update your question as it's more legible than in comments

Comment: Please check now